# Is there a way to make symbols in a table?

Tags: tables, symbols, mactex

I am trying to make a table and I keep getting errors once I add symbols like `\Theta`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\section{Problem 1}

%\begin{tabular}{l c r}
%f(n)    &     Bound       & g(n) \\
%n-100 & \Theta & n-200\\
%\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{ | l | c | r | }

n - 100 & \theta & n - 200\\

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's because the symbol requires a math font. Use `$\Theta$` and `$\theta$`...

Comment: thanks, new to latex and that helped me understand a LOT, solves a lot of errors I've been getting.

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because you are not in a math environment. Try inserting `\Theta` within `$ $`i.e. `$\Theta$`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\section{Problem 1}    
\begin{tabular}{ | l | c | r | }
   \hline
   $f(n)$    &     Bound       & $g(n)$\\
   \hline
   $n - 100$ & $\theta$ & $n - 200$\\
   \hline    
\end{tabular}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

I also added horizontal lines using `\hline`.

Comment: Since most of the table consists of math-mode material, it would be preferable to use an `array` environment, with a single pair of `$...$` delimiters encasing the `array` environment. That way, five pairs of inner `$...$` delimiters could be omitted. (The loan non-math item, "Bound", would have to be input as `\mbox{Bound}`.)

Comment: @Mico -- why not `\text` instead of `\mbox`, as long as `amsmath` is being used?

Comment: @barbarabeeton -- Ah, I had overlooked this little fact... Sure, since `amsmath` is being used, by all means use `\text` instead of `\mbox`.